# building own function to remove duplicate elements from list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to build a function which will remove all duplicates from a list. Suppose I start with the list [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4] and I only want to get [3,4] without repeated elements. How can i rewrite the following codes without using `elem`?

```
rmds :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
rmds [] = []
rmds [x] = [x]
rmds (x:xs)
  | elem x (xs) = [k|k <- rmds (xs) , k /= x]
  | otherwise = x : [c| c <- rmds (xs), c /=x]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `\\` operator to achieve what you want:

```hs
import Data.List
rmds :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
rmds [] = []
rmds [x] = [x]
rmds zs@(x:y:xs) = zs \\ dups zs
  where dups = concat . filter ((>1) . length) . group . sort
```

The core idea here is to find all the duplicates in the list, and then use `\\` to delete all the duplicates from the original list.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will actually work if you just remove that test.

```
rmds :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
rmds [] = []
rmds [x] = [x]
rmds (x:xs) = x : [c | c <- rmds xs, c /= x]
```

Can you see why? You also don't need the special case for `[x]`. Can you understand why?